# change ImageView based on the clicked spinner item its not working

Tags: android

I have 2 two images (item1.png and item2.png) and I want to show each image in a ImageView when the items on the spinner are clicked. When the "item1" in the spinner is selected I want to show the "item1.png" image and the same for the "item2".

Im trying to do this with the code below but its no working. Do you know what is the issue?

On MainActivity:

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        String string = String.valueOf(spinner.getSelectedItem());


        final ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
        int image1 = R.drawable.item1;
        int image2 = R.drawable.item2;

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            //spinner.
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                       int arg2) {
                if (arg2 == 0) {

                    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.item1);
                } else {
                    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.item2);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.ricardorei.tpc.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="199dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="58dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="58dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/item1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="321dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:text="Are Awesome!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.517"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="295dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="134dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:entries="@array/spinner_values"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.522"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change `OnItemSelectedListener` like below:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.item1);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.item2);
                        break;
                    default:
                        //Default image
                        //image.setImageResource(R.drawable.item2);
                        break;

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Do you know how to set the image invisiblity when the case 0 that is the item <item> Select a item</item> is selected? Im using image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) but its not working